# D3 albersUsa projection funtion return null

Tags: javascript, d3.js, projection

I'm pretty new to D3 and I'm trying to set point on a map.

I'm confused as I created a projection with this code:

```
var projection = d3.geo
      .albersUsa()
      .scale(500)
      .translate([el.clientWidth / 2, el.clientHeight / 2]);
```

I use this projection to draw a map and it works fine.

But then whenever I call `projection([10, 20])` it returns `null` whichever values I'm passing in.

What is my error?

Comment: what's `projection([10, 20])` supposed to do?

Comment: nothing wrong can you put it in a working fiddle

Comment: Here is a fiddle with my complete code, thanks to @altocumulus the projection is working: https://jsfiddle.net/teone/gzws1068/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation

> [# `projection(location)`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Projections.md#_projection)
>
> *[…]*
> May return null if the specified location has no defined projected position, such as when the location is outside the clipping bounds of the projection.

The Albers USA projection is defined only within its borders and will yield `null` for coordinates outside the well-defined area.

See this comparison of calls to `projection(location)` using `[10,20]`, which is not valid, and `[-110,40]`, which is a valid point:

```js
var projection = d3.geo
      .albersUsa()
      .scale(500)
      .translate([960, 500]);
      
d3.selectAll("p")
    .data([[10,20],[-110,40]])
  .enter().append("p")
    .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + projection(d); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I'm getting results. Do you know any issue in using this with `Force Layout`? I'm trying to fix some point in it, while let it calculate the position for others, But I can't position them, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/teone/gzws1068/11/