# Fail to parse/project coordinates onto JSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I am simply trying to draw a bunch of circles on the json map, with dynamic`cx` and `cy` properties as per the latitude and longitude coordinates that I parse through a csv.

For what it's worth, I have not had this issue in a long time, almost since I was TOTALLY new to d3. I read through all related posts, I looked back at beginner's tutorials (without shame), and I still can't catch what I did wrong. Please have a look, it's very short, key lines are 67-68. You may Find my json map here:

http://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/a2ace75c8ea89ab0da996154d3df7f5c

You will notice, no circles are appended. To my knowledge, I went about appending the circles in the orthodox D3.js manner:

1. create an empty selection.
2. bind data to doms
3. append visuals from data

If I did something stupid, by all means, drill it into me -- I'm psychologically strong, I can take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data contains some coordinates which are not within the well-defined area of the AlbersUSA projection. For more details see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35215345/4235784) to [*"D3 albersUsa projection funtion return null"*](/q/35214884). Because the projection will return `null` for these, you get an error, which breaks the creation of circles.

A naïve approach would be to filter out the non-valid coordinates:

```
var data = rawData.map(function(d)
{
    return {
        Latitude: +d.latitude,
        Longitude: +d.longitude,
        Place: d.place
    };
})
.filter(d => projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude]));   // filter out null values
```

This will [display the circles](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/eb68015a65557c8c5fe764226e926000) on the map. However, you might want to check your data first and try to sift them out beforehand.

Comment: wow, that did it. Good thinking, I never would have thought to examine it from the data side.

Comment: By the way, if the coordinates are in the ocean, close to land, it will also be null? For example the water around Hawaii?

Comment: That depends on the coordinates. Do you have a specific example?

Comment: @ArashHowaida It doesn't matter if it's in the ocean or on land, though. Have a look at this [Block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5629120) which depicts the narrow bounds of Alaska and Hawaii.

Comment: Thanks again, your help has been invaluable. I have one more follow up question. After I chained in the `.filter()` to the data mapping section at the start of the code, I also want to add another filter to only append circles in Southern California. So in the append circle section, after `.data(data)` I added this: `.filter( function(d) { return (Math.abs(d.Latitude-34)<2) && (Math.abs(d.Longitude-116)<2);})` For some reason, it seems to be filtering out everything and I get the error .data().enter() is not a function.